# Flyway does not insert values to database

Tags: java, sql, configuration, flyway

I added flyway library to my spring project. I configurated it and wrote some instuctions, project compiles but flyway does not insert values provided into data base.
Config of application.yml:

```
 flyway:
  baseline-on-migrate: true
  enabled: false
```

Impl:
[ressource folder]

[image: 1]

SQL instructions that must be insert:

```
 insert role(name) values ('ROLE_USER');
 insert role(name) values ('ROLE_ADMIN');
```

But after running application, they dont figure in database. The table is being created but fields are null.

Comment: Did you try the set up the configuration on the application.yml file?
I found very some explanation in this article:
https://www.baeldung.com/database-migrations-with-flyway

Comment: I guess that the migration will happen only if you trigger it. 
`mvn clean flyway:migrate`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed bug. I just had to change 'enabled' to true:

```
 enabled: true
```

Answer (score 0):

you should create 2 files:

1. schema
2. new data

[image]